# Is it possible to get a full Gmail history and export it on a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Big premise: I know nothing about coding, but I think it may be the solution. I apologize in advance for any rookie mistakes regarding the matter (also spelling ones, as english is not my first language).

Background: very important emails have been deleted from an institutional account, even from the trash. I've managed to restore them by the Gmail Admin Console, via "restore data" option.
Retrieving said emails wasn't an issue.
Proving that those email were deleted in the first place, however, it is.

Looking for solutions day and night, I stumbled upon Gmail APIs, especially something called users.history.list. I had no luck in obtaining valuable results (again, I know nothing about coding).

So, my question is:
Is there a way to get a full Gmail History, proving that those emails were deleted in the first place, and export said results somewhere (ig. a Google Spreadsheet)?

I'm asking because legal action has to be taken, and this could be a start.

Thank you in advance, again, I apologize if this is not the right format but i runned out of ideas at the moment...

Comment: You can try to use the API explorer in Gmail API reference to explore what's available.

Comment: "_legal action has to be taken_" - You may get help here (but there are no guarantees). Given you mentioned the "L"-word, I would strongly encourage you to contact Google directly as well (if you have not already done so).  I understand that finding anyone may be a challenge, of course.